# How to stack a 2D array on a 3D array in Numpy

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros((3, 4))
b = np.zeros((3, 4))
ab = np.stack((a, b), axis=0)
```

I want to stack `b` in the axis=0 direction of `ab`.

```
abb = np.stack((ab, b), axis=0)  # ERROR
abb = np.vstack((ab, b))  # also ERROR
abb = np.vstack((ab, b[np.newaxis, ...]))  # This is OK, but it seems redundant
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: reshape the 2d array to 3d

Answer (score 0):

As @Vishesh Mangla suggested:

```
b=b.reshape(1,3,4)
abb = np.vstack((ab, b))
```

Comment: Thanks for adding to @Vishesh Mangla comments.
But the ``reshape`` idea seems to be the same as the code using ``np.newaxis``.
When stacking a 1D array on a 2D array, it can be written as:
    ``a = np.zeros(3);``
    ``b = np.zeros(3);``
    ``ab = np.stack((a, b), axis=0);``
    ``abb = np.vstack((ab, b));``
Why can I do this, but not in 3D?